# Why are Color, Typography and Shape variables in pascal case in Jetpack Compose project in Android Studio?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

In latest jetpack compose project in Android Studio (in my case Android Studio Giraffe)

Why are Color, Typography and Shape variables in pascal case in Jetpack Compose project in Android Studio?

No, I haven't tried anything.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It was based on the [Jetpack Compose API Guidelines](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/docs/compose-api-guidelines.md#singletons-constants-sealed-class-and-enum-class-values)

It says that

> Jetpack Compose framework development MUST name deeply immutable constants following the permitted object declaration convention of PascalCase as documented [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#property-names) as a replacement for any usage of CAPITALS_AND_UNDERSCORES. Enum class values MUST also be named using PascalCase as documented in the same section.

Color, Typography, and Shape variables are constants

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. But Why does Android Studio show this "Private property name 'LightColors' doesn't match regex '_?[a-z][A-Za-z\d]*'" warning? I think it shouldn't. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Did you get the warning on private variables such as `LightColors`? You can hover over the variable name and click the three dots on the top right, and then click the *Show Inspection Description*. 
This was written on the description: "According to the Kotlin official style guide, private property names should start with a lowercase letter and use camel case."